# Assign string stored in memory into a GDB variable

Tags: c, string, gdb

When debugging a C program, how can I assign a string (array of bytes terminated by `\0` byte) stored at some known memory location into a GDB [convenience variable](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Convenience-Vars.html)?

**E.g.**:
There is a string `"hello_world"` stored at memory location `0xAAAAAAAA`, how can I store the string into a GDB variable `string_variable` using that memory location? Using `(gdb) set $string_Variable = (char *) 0xAAAAAAAA` stores the address and not the string itself.

Comment: graphics debugger using gdb will make it more convenient

Answer (score 2):

A string convenience variable in GDB is an array of `char`:

```
(gdb) set $foo = "bbb"
(gdb) ptype $foo
type = char [4]
```

Using GDB's CLI, I can't find a straightforward way to create a string convenience variable from an address of a NUL-terminated string of bytes in the debuggee.

What does work is to use GDB's Python extension to get a [gdb.Value](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Values-From-Inferior.html) from the debuggee, then convert it to a string:

```
(gdb) python gdb.set_convenience_variable("string_variable", gdb.parse_and_eval("(char *)0x555555556011").string()) 
(gdb) ptype $string_variable
type = char [12]
(gdb) p $string_variable
$3 = "hello_world"
```